# How does a WebSocket key work?

Tags: browser, websocket

Recently I have been researching WebSockets, I think they are very cool. However, if I take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Protocol_handshake), some things are unclear for me.

Request:

```
GET /chat HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: x3JJHMbDL1EzLkh9GBhXDw==
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat, superchat
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: http://example.com
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: HSmrc0sMlYUkAGmm5OPpG2HaGWk=
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat
```

The requester specifies the host, so intermediate servers will know where the request should arrive. The requester sends a random string encoded into base64 and the server sends back a salted SHA1-encrypted key back. Will this key be used between the two while the connection is alive? If so, is there a way this key can be reused even if the connection was broken?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it's mentioned in your Wikipedia link:

> In addition to Upgrade headers, the client sends a Sec-WebSocket-Key header containing base64-encoded random bytes, and the server replies with a hash of the key in the Sec-WebSocket-Accept header. **This is intended to prevent a caching proxy from re-sending a previous WebSocket conversation, and does not provide any authentication, privacy or integrity.**

`Sec-WebSocket-Key` is only used inside the handshake and isn't used for the actual communication.

The key is meant to prevent proxies from caching the request, by sending a random key. If the proxy still returns a cached response, it can be checked by validating the `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` header.

The client could ignore the `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` header (and hope the response isn't cached) and the WebSocket protocol would still work normally.
In such case the server could be implemented to ignore the `Sec-WebSocket-Key` header and not return the `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` header.

How to generate the `Sec-WebSocket-Accept` header for response or validation can be read inside this answer:
[generate "Sec-WebSocket-Accept" from "Sec-WebSocket-Key"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35977916/generate-sec-websocket-accept-from-sec-websocket-key/35989898#35989898)

Answer (score 1):

> The hashing function appends the fixed string
> 258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11 (a GUID) to the value from
> Sec-WebSocket-Key header (which is not decoded from base64), applies
> the SHA-1 hashing function, and encodes the result using base64.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket#Protocol%20handshake

More info at: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.3