# Websocket handshake doesnt work

Tags: javascript, c++, websocket

i have a cpp server using WinSock2 and im trying to connect to this server with my javascript client, and it doesnt work, the chrome console says "Error during WebSocket handshake: Incorrect 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header value".
i compared my sha1 and base64 functions with online sha1 and base64 so the problem isnt here.

**Chrome Response Header:**

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-Websocket-Accept: NzdkYjg1Y2I4MDRlNTk0OGNmNzI1NzdjZDgwOTEwZWZiYWI1NzQ3Yw==
```

**Chrome Request Header:**

```
GET ws://localhost:8820/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8820
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: file://
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: he-IL,he;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Sec-WebSocket-Key: Y7a2ZKEz/VCM92Wya49iPA==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
```

**Server Code:**

```
//key is already defined.
key += "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";
key = sha1(key);
key = base64_encode(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(key.c_str()), key.length());

toClient = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n";
toClient += "Upgrade: websocket\r\n";
toClient += "connection: Upgrade\r\n";
toClient += "Sec-Websocket-Accept: ";
toClient += key; 
toClient += "\r\n\r\n";

sendData(sc, toClient);
```

**Client Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     function WebSocketTest()
     {
        if ("WebSocket" in window)
        {
           //alert("WebSocket is supported by your Browser!");

           // Let us open a web socket
           var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8820");
           console.log("test");
           ws.onopen = function()
           {
                alert("Connection.")
                // Web Socket is connected, send data using send()
                ws.send("20304user04user04user");
                //alert("Message is sent...");
           };

           ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
           { 
              var received_msg = evt.data;
              alert("Hey");
           };

           ws.onclose = function()
           { 
              // websocket is closed.
              alert("Connection is closed..."); 
           };
        }

        else
        {
           // The browser doesn't support WebSocket
           alert("WebSocket NOT supported by your Browser!");
        }
     }
  </script>
```

```
  <div id="sse">
     <a href="javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Should you maybe connect with wss and not ws?

Comment: I don't see a reason to do that, my code should work, do you have any more suggestions?

Comment: could you share the request response headers of the handshake from the developer tools network?

Comment: I updated the question with the request & response headers.

Comment: It's probably not related but the response connection header from the server: `connection: Upgrade` should start with upper case `Connection: Upgrade`

Comment: Have you properly initialized `key` before appending the GUID?

Comment: @amiramw , I changed the 'c' to capital letter c and still the same problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah i actually did, look at the key output between the '{' and '}', [link](http://prntscr.com/fdt7n6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried manually to build the response:

1. Raw sha1 digest bytes of the concatenation are `77db85cb804e5948cf72577cd80910efbab5747c`
2. Bytes to base 64: `d9uFy4BOWUjPcld82AkQ77q1dHw=`

This is different than what you have. You are transforming the hexadecimal string representation of those bytes to base 64 instead of raw bytes to base 64.

Comment: So I used [this](http://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/development/Base64/Encoding-and-decoding-base-64-with-cpp) method for the base64 and it seems good to me, I think I don't really get the problem

Comment: @FlyingNades The base64 encoding is not the problem. Your sha1 function is. Check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35989898) on a similar question. It might make your problem clearer.

Comment: @gre_gor so neither the sha1 or the base64 functions are the problem, the sha1 representation I send to the base64 functions is the problem, am I right?

Comment: @gre_gor and also, if you're willing to help me I'd like to know how can I do this in cpp, I've been searching for too long now..

Comment: @FlyingNades, if you set hard coded the response in your cpp code to d9uFy4BOWUjPcld82AkQ77q1dHw= does it work?

Comment: @amiramw No, because every time the client generate a new key so the response accept key is no longer the same, How did you get to the second result? (with the bytes)

Comment: Oh right. I used http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en